# Issues Booting Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Server) after cloning from another drive

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gparted

I have an Ubuntu server running 18.04 LTS. Not long ago, I had to clone the drive of this server to another machine to make repairs, and now I need to reclone it back to the server again. This time, I used the GParted boot disk following [these instructions here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/clone-a-linux-hard-drive-with-gparted/#:%7E:text=To%20copy%20a%20partition%20in,to%20it%20in%20the%20app.) to copy the boot and EXT4 partitions from the second drive to the server.

After cloning the drive back. I tried to reboot the server but it just went into an infinite reboot loop after trying to start the drive. I'm assuming something got messed up with the grub configuration, so I next created a Boot-repair-Disk on a USB drive and followed [these instructions here](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) to try and repair Grub. Unfortunately, It failed, but I had it output the error report and posted it here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4gbg8F4xnH/

Onne user on the Ubuntu forum suggested that I clear the file system from the grub partition and try the Boot-Repair-Disk again. But I tried it and it still gave the same error: Here's an updated pastebin from the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pGrtVWzWgm/

Here's what GParted shows for the curent partition setup:

[image]

I'm not sure what to try next. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally found a solution. I created a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (SERVER) boot disk, and was able to use it's repair option to reinstall Grub and get it to boot. Here's the guide I followed to get it to work:

https://www.tecmint.com/rescue-repai...in-ubuntu/amp/

Hope this helps in case anyone runs into a similar issue.